# Apache2 doesn't work after listening to audio player for a time

Tags: php, apache2, html5-audio

I have a problem with my website. I have a cms where you can login. When you are logged in, you have the possibility to listen to a stream with an  Player. After a time (it's always different, most ~ 3 min.) the player stops working and I can't visit any pages (on the same server) and everything loads very long (ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR). For other persons, everything works fine at the same time but only for the listener of this stream, it stucks. 
After ~ 30 sec. everything works fine and I can visit every page normally but when I again start the  player, the same problem appears after some minutes.

How can I fix this problem?

Thank in advance!

```
<audio style="width: 100%" id ="player" controls><source src="LINK" type="audio/mp3" width="100%" >Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>
```

Comment: which player do you use? I met similar problem but after changing player lib to http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/ it seems to eliminate. I'd advise you to watch server side processes with `htop` Linux console command

Comment: I am using the html5-audio player with <audio> - I will try your lib, thank you very much!

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with PHP? Are you loading the audio file through PHP or are you linking the audio tag directly to the audio file?

Comment: So the cms works in PHP and I am linking the audio tag directly to the audio file with <source src="LINK" type="audio/mp3">

Comment: I have also noticed that this problem only appears on chromium-based browsers